# How to justify NAVBAR items in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has two separate components, the nav and the navbar. The nav allows you to use the `nav-justified`class in order to get a nice justified navbar in which the items are evenly distributed across the screen.

But the nav does not have numerous other nice features which I need, whereas the navbar DOES have all these but does *not* seem have a nav-justified option.

Does anyone know the solution to this? Applying the `nav-justified` class to a navbar is catastrophic, before anyone suggests that, thanks in advance on that one.

Comment: can you show your example in http://www.bootply.com/new ?

Comment: No....since it requires resizing the screen as part of knowing whether it works, and Bootply requires a certain min screen size.